# index() with bool value in list unpacking

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
def fn(box):
    for x in box:
            print(type(x), x, box.index(x))
    print("")
list_1 = [1, "a", [1, 2], True]

fn(list_1)
```

I have a easy question why method index() for boolean True return index value 0 and don't return value 3 ?
and how do id correcty.

Comment: because `True == 1`, and indeed, `True == 1.0`, `True == decimal.Decimal('0.0')` etc etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Your point is correct, but you meant `False == decimal.Decimal('0.0')` or `True == decimal.Decimal('1.0')`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger whoops, yes, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`bool` is a subclass of `int` which has only two values, `False` with a value of `0` and `True` with a value of `1`. They are in fact equal to the equivalent `int` (and `float`, and `complex`, and `decimal.Decimal`, etc.) values, in the same way that `1` and `1.0` are equal (`.index(1.0)` would find `1` as well).

In this case, the correct (and much faster) solution is to just make your loop give you the index in the first place, effectively for free, rather than running a pointless scan for the value it just gave you, [with `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def fn(box):
    for i, x in enumerate(box):
            print(type(x), x, i)
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` for this case:

```
for i, x in enumerate(box):
    print(type(x), x, i)
```